# Make original Observable complete when the one inside flatMap completes

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have an `Observable` on which I'm applying the `flatMap` operator. Is it possible to make this original `Observable` complete when the second one completes?

Here is the code.

```
Observable.never<Int>()
        .startWith(0)
        .doOnComplete { println("Completed") } // Not called.
        .flatMap { Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) /* Completes after 5 */ }
        .subscribe(::println)
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm trying to achieve the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of operator `materialize` which will help you get information about what is hapening inside `flatMap`. Then you can dispose upstream when you receive `onComplete` notification(by taking only `onNext` Notifications).

```
    Observable.<Integer>never()
            .startWith(0)
            .flatMap(integer -> Observable.range(1, 5)
                    .materialize())
            .takeWhile(notification -> notification.isOnNext())
            .map(notification -> notification.getValue())
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
            .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer));
```

Result

```
1
2
3
4
5
Completed
```